# Is using model checkpoint a good idea?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a CNN code that determines if an image contains violence, drugs, horror, or sexual content. I am currently in the phase of training the CNN and trying out different configurations to find the best accuracy with my CNN. With this training I implemented `from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint` to utilize checkpoints while training. I use callbacks like this:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(WEIGHTS_PATH, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                    steps_per_epoch=3000,
                    epochs = 10,
                    validation_data = test_set,
                    validation_steps = 300,
                    callbacks = [checkpoint])
```

So every iteration of epoch, the epoch with the highest val_acc will be saved to a .hdf5 file. My question is, Is this a good practice? or Is this a good way to code CNN? I mean even if the epochs are not finished, the epoch that yielded the highest val_acc will be the only one saved and every other iteration with lower val_acc is ignored. I am kinda new to CNN so I want to know as much as possible for me to be able to achieve a good CNN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the validation accuracy is an estimation to see how your model generalises on unseen data. So when you are saving checkpoints with best validation accuracy , what happens is you are saving the weight(the ones which are learned by training) that best predicts results for the unseen data. So by having multiple checkpoints saved you can utilize these checkpoints when testing the model with test data( which may be taken from say a real time use case), and select the model which works well with your test data

Hope this helps